# Automatic login on website

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, postman, axios

I'm developing a code solution on NodeJS to log automatically at this website http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl I have a problem at momento of authentication but I do the same thing on Postman App and that works great but my code isn't.

```
let axios = require('axios');
let cheerio = require('cheerio');
let queryString = require('querystring');

let login = async function () {
try {
    let response = await axios.get('http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl');
    let $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    let cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
    cookie[0] = cookie[0].split(';')[0];
    cookie[1] = cookie[1].split(';')[0];
    console.log(cookie);
    let token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
    let subdominio = $('input[name="subdominio"]').val();
    let body = {
        _token: token,
        subdominio: subdominio,
        login: '**********',
        password: '***************'
    }
    let options = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            Accept: '*/*',
            Connection: 'keep-alive',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
            cookie: cookie
        }
    }
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
    console.log(queryString.stringify(body));
    console.log('--------------------------------------');
    let loggedPageData = await axios.post('http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl/auth/login',
        queryString.stringify(body), options);
    let loggedCookies = loggedPageData.headers['set-cookie'];
    options = {
        headers: {
            cookie: loggedCookies
        }
    }        
    console.log(loggedPageData);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
}

login();
```

I hope the result is the html code of http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl/home as the result of Postman request.

The actual result is the login html code http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl/ or http://panel2.gpscontrol.cl/auth/login

Comment: I don't think the direct 'set-cookie' header is what browsers typically send back as the cookie, verbatim. The set-cookie header includes the domain= and expires= keys.

Comment: Thanks @audiodude I've made the request using XMLHttpRequest and that works well.